# Babel ignore equivalent in ember engines?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs, ember-addon, ember-engines

In a traditional Ember app, I have something along the lines of this in my `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
//ember-cli-build.js
module.exports = function(defaults) {
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    babel: {
        includePolyfill: true,
        ignore: ['my-ember-ui/models/myFile.js'] // <-- question is here
    },
```

Is there an equivalent to this when using an Ember Engine (or addon)?  I couldn't find anything within ember-cli-babel or ember-engines.

I understand that `ember-cli-build.js` is just for the dummy app when using an engine, so I wouldn't make the change there. I attempted similar to above in the `index.js` file, but did not have any luck.  The file was not ignored by babel.  I need a way to ignore a particular file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, adding new rules to Cli.build.js is ok depends on what you want to do. However, I may have another solution that you can give it a try.

Babel will look for a `.babelrc` in the current directory of the file being transpiled. If one does not exist, it will travel up the directory tree until it finds either a `.babelrc`, or a `package.json` with a `"babel": {}` hash within.(.babelrc files are serializable JSON).

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"],
  "ignore": [
    "foo.js",
    "bar/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "babel": {
    // my babel config here
  }
}
```

There should be another way which seems ok to use. the following does work:

```
babel src --out-dir build --ignore "**/*.test.js"  // or simply add your file
```

For more information, you can read [Babel document](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/)